# EF one to many Update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many

I have some problems update the data with the relationship one to many.
Here is My Entity

```
public class Customer : Entity
{
    public Customer()
    {
        ContactPersons = new List<ContactPerson>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 客户编号
    /// </summary>
    public string Code { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 客户名称
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public ICollection<ContactPerson> ContactPersons { get; set; }
}


/// <summary>
/// 联系人实体
/// </summary>
public class ContactPerson : Entity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 姓名
    /// </summary>
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string QQ { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

In the Configuration class,the code is:

```
HasMany(f => f.ContactPersons).WithRequired(f => f.Customer).Map(f => f.MapKey("CustomerId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I think the mapping is right,add or delete works fine,only update throw exceptions.

"Customer_ContactPersons" in AssociationSet is "Deleted". If there are multiple constraints, the corresponding "Customer_ContactPersons_Target" must also is "Deleted".

```
public void Update(CustomerEditViewModel model)
    {
        var customerDb = _customerRep.GetAll().NotLazy(f => f.ContactPersons).SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == model.Id);

        //customerDb.ContactPersons.Clear(); can not work either!!

        var count = customerDb.ContactPersons.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            customerDb.ContactPersons.Remove(customerDb.ContactPersons.ElementAt(i));
            count--;
        }

        _customerRep.Update(customerDb);
    }
```

I want to Clear the List of ContactPersons in Customer ,how to...

Comment: The error is in Chinese :D

Comment: it means the soruce is deleted,the target msut be deteted too...i think..

Comment: You should set either `True` or `False` inside `WillCascadeOnDelete();" Check the documentation for changing the Entities states!

Comment: set to true dose not work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing the relationship between the `Customer` and `ContactPerson` entities without deleting the `ContactPerson` entity.

Rewrite your method as below to remove the associated `ContactPerson` entities instead.

```
public void Update(CustomerEditViewModel model)
{
    var customerDb = _customerRep.GetAll().NotLazy(f => f.ContactPersons).SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == model.Id);

    foreach(var contactPerson in customerDb.ContactPersons.ToList())
    {
        _customerRep.Delete(contactPerson);
    }

}
```

Comment: this works fine, but nhibernate can delete child objects through update the parent...why ef can not.